# codeigniter's csv_from_result returns only field names

Tags: codeigniter, export-to-csv

I'm trying to output a query result as a csv file, using `csv_from_result`, but for some reason, it only echoes the field names, and not the full results, like so:
`"code","heb_name","eng_name","intro","heb_code","rank"`

This is the code I'm using, based on CI documentation [here](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/utilities.html?highlight=csv_from_result#CI_DB_utility::csv_from_result):

```
$query = $this->db->query($sql);

if($query->result()) {
    $this->load->dbutil();

    $delimiter = ",";
    $newline = "\r\n";

    echo $this->dbutil->csv_from_result($query, $delimiter, $newline);
}
```

`$sql` holds the query syntax, but I dont give it here since I get the same results even with the simplest `"SELECT * FROM table"` query.

The query itself does return full results. When I'm dumping `$query->result_array()` I get the expected result array.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Personally i prefer PHPExcel. make sure you setup proper headers and encoding. try this:

```
$this->load->dbutil();
$query = $this->db->query($sql);

if($query->result()) {

    $delimiter = ",";
    $newline = "\r\n";

    header ("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=csv_file" . time() . ".csv") ;
    echo mb_convert_encoding($this->dbutil->csv_from_result($query, $delimiter, $newline), "ISO-8859-1", "UTF-8");
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But adding the encoding conversion and setting the headers didn't change anything. I'm still getting only field names, no content.